# Why do I get the exception - Unable to load DLL '?????.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: dll, image-processing, interop, opencv

I'm using Emgu.CV which is a C# wrapper for the OpenCV libraries.

I changed the Emgu.CV source to invoke from the latest OpenCV library cv110.dll instead of cv100.dll and now I get this error (where ????? is cv110.dll). I have placed the cv110.dll file in all the same locations as the cv100.dll file however this does not help.

On a broader scale, what is the folder search order when looking for dlls, and are there anyone other reasons for this error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a subtle difference between those two assemblies. Without code its hard to tell, but I suggest you to take a look to this blog, specially this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/08/11/57236.aspx
Suzanne Cooks worked in the fusion/CLR loader, and her blogs has tons of tips and advices for this kind of issues.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need VCRT(Visual C run time) 8.0 SP1, available from the following link:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=200B2FD9-AE1A-4A14-984D-389C36F85647&displaylang=en

See this post on Emgu CV discussion forum for more information:
http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=88